# What is the difference between storage online and on computer when using Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

I have set Dropbox up on my Windows 10 computer to sync all files and folders (i.e: No selective sync). However the online version says I have 79GB space being used and my computer only shows 42GBof space being used. I cannot work out which files are missing but clearly about half my data is.

Comment: Are you using "[Selective Sync](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/selective-sync-overview)"?

Comment: No. Under selective sync my settings are "Select All" and all boxes are ticked

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear you this as Dropbox is a file synchronization service and it keeps a copy of data you have stored on your local drive. Usually, the dropbox folder is available Users folder.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand though why this means that there would be 50% less data on my windows computer than online?

Comment: You might have used selective sync option that removes a folder from the hard drive but keep it on the online account.

Comment: I have confirmed that selective sync is not all. All folders are set to sync. This is why I am so confused